# duplicate words in memory game

Tags: c#

I have a problem with duplicates words in memory game.

I have a code (bellow) and what I want to duplicate labels and pass it (in random position every time when app is open) to bellow row e.g

Open app first time

---

| label1 | label2 | label3 | <= first row

---

| label3 | label2 | label1 | <= second row

---

Open app second time

---

| label1 | label2 | label3 | <= first row

---

| label1 | label3 | label2 | <= second row

---

```cs
private void AssingWordsToSquares()
        {
            Label label;
            int randomNumber;
            string path = $"{_currentPath}\\Resources\\Words.txt";
            _loadWordsList = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
               
                if (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] is Label)
                {
                    label = (Label)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i];                  
                }
                else
                    continue;
                
                randomNumber = random.Next(0, _loadWordsList.Count);
                label.Text = _loadWordsList[randomNumber];

                _loadWordsList.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
            }

``
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the problem is?

Comment: I want to duplicate words in .txt file. I generate random words with this file but i can't to duplicate this same words what i need to use in memory game

Comment: You're making a memory game of pairs? Where you turn over one card and have to remember where you saw the other same card before?

Comment: Yes, i have .txt file where i have a 100 words to use. I generate this words random from this file but i don't know how to duplicate words when they been generate automatically. It's possible to do or I must to copy all the words twice and then generate?

Comment: Alright, if you are opening and closing the app over and over again, you can write the words you have extracted to another text file (call this Random.txt), and read the words from that. However, I will warn you this is bad practice. Instead, make a "Reset" button inside the app that reshuffles the words. That way, you can store the random words in a List<string> object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

So, at the moment, the function you shared is doing 2 things.

- 1 is to find `random` words from a dictionary in a file
- 2 is to place the words in a `random` order on screen

So you have 2 random operations happening.  Remember the golden rule which is 1 function should try and do just 1 thing. It should have just 1 purpose.

So, you could seperate out that functionality to make it clearer.

We could start by creating a function that will generate a random list of words from your dictionary file.  Something like this:

```
List<string> GenerateRandomWords(int numWords)
{
    var randomWordList = new List<string>();

    var wordList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("RandomWords.txt").ToList();

    for (int nLoopCnt = 0; nLoopCnt < numWords; nLoopCnt++)
    {
        var randomNumber = random.Next(0, wordList.Count);
        randomWordList.Add(wordList[randomNumber]);
    }

    return randomWordList;
}
```

Now you have your random words extracted from the file we need to put them on the screen in a random order.  So, we could create another function `GenerateRandomPosOrder` that takes a TableLayoutPanel and generates a list of columns in a random order. So, each time you run this function is could return `1,2,3` or `1,3,2` or `3,2,1`.

```
private HashSet<int> GenerateRandomPosOrder(TableLayoutPanel table)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Random rnd = new Random();

    var result = new HashSet<int>();

    while (result.Count < table.ColumnCount)
    {
        var randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, table.ColumnCount);

        result.Add(randomNumber);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now we can put these 2 functions together in your `AssignWordsToSquares` like so.

```
private void AssignWordsToSquares(TableLayoutPanel table)
{
    var wordList = GenerateRandomWords(table.ColumnCount);

    // loop around every row in the table
    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < table.RowCount; rowCount++)
    {
        // this could return 0,2,1 or 1,0,2 or 1,2,0
        var order = GenerateRandomPosOrder(table);

        int pos = 0;
        foreach (var randomPosition in order)
        {
            var tableCell = (Label)table.GetControlFromPosition(column: randomPosition, row: rowCount);

            tableCell.Text = wordList[pos++];
        }
    }
}
```

The above function first gets a list of random words from the dictionary, then for ever row of the TableLayoutPanel it puts the words in a random order.